# Fetch all the values of specific property in aem using queryBuilder

Tags: aem

I am having scenario in which i want to fetch all the values of a property under a specific path in AEM using QueryBuilder api.
This property can have single or multivalued.
Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: if i understand correctly **are you looking for the query which results the list of content path nodes** ? OR to **retrieve the property values alone for a specific content path** ?. So far AFAIK the query builder is used to retrieve the content paths for a specific search matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to fetch the properties using query builder api. I would suggest you to create a servlet resource, which requires a `path` and `property` name.

Fetch the jcr node using the given path via `QueryBuilder`. Then, you need to loop through the results to check the property of the nodes. You can access the multiple property values, once you have a node.

Answer (score 4):

Example that can help you. is below as it is just for illustration written in simple JSP scriptlets

```
 <%
Iterator<Resource> iter = resourceResolver.findResources("/jcr:root/content/geometrixx-outdoors//element(*, nt:unstructured)[(@imageRotate = '0' or @imageRotate = '1')]","xpath");
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Resource child = iter.next();
    out.println("</br>"+child.getPath());
    Node node = child.adaptTo(Node.class);
    Property nProp = node.getProperty("imageRotate");

if(nProp.isMultiple()) // This condition checks for properties whose type is String[](String array)  
      {  
Value[] values = nProp.getValues();
    out.println(" :: This is a multi valued property ::");
    for (Value v : values) {
        out.println("</br>"+"Property Name = "+nProp.getName()+" ; Property Value= "+v.getString());
    }  
      }  
      else if(!nProp.getDefinition().isMultiple()){  
          out.println("</br>"+"Property Name = "+nProp.getName()+" ; Property Value= "+nProp.getString());
      }  
}
%>
```

Here i have used the `Iterator<Resource> iter = resourceResolver.findResources(query,"xpath");` which can give you the query results which matches the `imageRotate` property under `/content/geometrixx-outdoors/` path which consists combination of single and multivalued as shown in below screenshot.

[image: CRX Node]